# psycopg2.errors.InvalidFunctionDefinition: create function must specify volatility attribute (IMMUTABLE|STABLE|VOLATILE)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a User defiend function in AWS Redshift using psycopg2, heres' the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_create_table_statement(p_table_name varchar)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_table_ddl   text;
    column_record record;
BEGIN
    FOR column_record IN 
        SELECT 
            b.nspname as schema_name,
            b.relname as table_name,
            a.attname as column_name,
            pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as column_type,
            CASE WHEN 
                (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
                 FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                 WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef) IS NOT NULL THEN
                'DEFAULT '|| (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
                              FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                              WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef)
            ELSE
                ''
            END as column_default_value,
            CASE WHEN a.attnotnull = true THEN 
                'NOT NULL'
            ELSE
                'NULL'
            END as column_not_null,
            a.attnum as attnum,
            e.max_attnum as max_attnum
        FROM 
            pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
            INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT c.oid,
                n.nspname,
                c.relname
              FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                   LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
              WHERE c.relname ~ ('^('||p_table_name||')$')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
              ORDER BY 2, 3) b
            ON a.attrelid = b.oid
            INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT 
                  a.attrelid,
                  max(a.attnum) as max_attnum
              FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
              WHERE a.attnum > 0 
                AND NOT a.attisdropped
              GROUP BY a.attrelid) e
            ON a.attrelid=e.attrelid
        WHERE a.attnum > 0 
          AND NOT a.attisdropped
        ORDER BY a.attnum
    LOOP
        IF column_record.attnum = 1 THEN
            v_table_ddl:='CREATE TABLE '||column_record.schema_name||'.'||column_record.table_name||' (';
        ELSE
            v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||',';
        END IF;

        IF column_record.attnum <= column_record.max_attnum THEN
            v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||chr(10)||
                     '    '||column_record.column_name||' '||column_record.column_type||' '||column_record.column_default_value||' '||column_record.column_not_null;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||');';
    RETURN v_table_ddl;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidFunctionDefinition: create function must specify volatility attribute 
(IMMUTABLE|STABLE|VOLATILE)
```

Where exactly do I put this attribute in my query? I've looked around but found no examples that did this.

Comment: Don't look "around", look in the actual manuals.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html

After the language "plpgsql" is typical.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html
You forgot to specify the volatility attribute. It need to be specified after the 'return' statement like this:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_create_table_statement(p_table_name varchar)
RETURNS text
**stable**
AS
$BODY$

Furthermore it seems, that plpgsql is not a supported language for function creation at redshift.
Supported languages:
$$ LANGUAGE { plpythonu | sql }